# How to redirect page while getting error in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I got this error in MVC. when i get this error i want to redirect one error page. How to do?

The Error is:

> Error:
>
> An Error Occurred While Processing Your Request.

Comment: Please Give me your Source Code.

Comment: This is such a generic error, it's impossible for anyone to have any insight into what causes it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use try catch.

Given below is an example. Hope it helps

```
    // action method for same
    [HttpPost]  
    public ActionResult Save(EmployeeModel employeeModel)
    {

        try
        {
            // do something, like call a service/business layer method.

            // redirect to home action
             return RedirectToAction("Home");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // if failure gets into catch block and returns the posted model back, 
            // work aroud for viewstate(does not exist in asp.net mvc) using model binding in asp.net mvc
            return View(employeeModel);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply try catch block and in catch block use redirection code to redirect the web page ... I hope this will help you

Comment: I am using reportviewer in my application, but in publish area there is no dll reference for report. I handle try catch block, but that reference issue not come to catch block. Only that error occured.